# Highchart graph customization not performing well

Tags: highcharts

I am using high chart graph to display data in this graph by current month.I want to display four weeks of the month in x-axis and want to show data for the whole month.I am giving my working js fiddle :

```
**http://jsfiddle.net/Rw69Y/2/**
```

Everything is working fine except I just want to show four monday of this month. i.e (2014-04-07,2014-04-14,2014-04-21,2014-04-28).Any idea about it?I am stuck on there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set **tickInterval** please see this fiddle-`**http://jsfiddle.net/Rw69Y/21/**`

Comment: also how to remove series 1 text from below

Comment: I have updated js fiddle link. Please see the code from fiddle

Comment: Its working fine. One last thing, how can I remove highcharts.com link from below.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set `tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600000`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Rw69Y/10/